# Can JQuery detect new classes as they appear? E.G. new comment that has just been posted

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a micropost/commenting system and each time a new micropost or comment is submitted the page refreshes in order to display it.

Since I've setup up ajax on my form I'd now like to have the micropost or added without the page refreshing.

So far I have:

```
if @micropost.save
  format.js   { render :post_on_wall }
else
  format.js   { render :form_errors }
end
```

You don't need to be a ruby on rails expert to understand what's going on in this snippet. If the form passes all validation and user actually types in something valid before clicking post then "if @micropost.save" will be true and it will execute the js inside a file I have named "post_on_wall". If if "@micropost.save" the code inside "form_errors" will be executed.

Inside form_errors I added an alert just to check the micropost doesn't get posted when a user enters nothing and clicks post. It works fine.

In the "post_on_wall" file I have this:

```
$('.microposts').prepend('<%= j render("users/partials/microposts") %>');
```

The problem with this is it basically grabs all the microposts that are looped through in the file thats being rendered "users/partials/**microposts**" then places them above everything thats in the ".microposts" div. Even the actual form to post a micropost located at the top of the ".microposts" is pushed down below the contents that was just added to the page.

Here is my html structure.

```
<div class='cf' id='content'>
    <div id='leftColumn'>
    </div>
    <div class='microposts'>
    </div>
    <div id='rightColumn'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each micropost along with its associated comments is stored inside a class called ".postHolder".

I feel I'm going about this the wrong way. The file this: "users/partials/microposts" points to basically has code that helps display 10 microposts at a time. This is used for something completely different from what I'm trying to do (pagination + endless scrolling).

Anyway I feel the way I should be approaching this is to some how detect the new post that has just been posted. It should be detected as a new ".postHolder" class and then after it is found it should be added to the top of the list of "postHolder"'s and not replace the micropost form above it.

I'm thinking to just create a separate div to hold all microposts and then place this div underneath the micropost form.. that way I won't need to worry about the form being pushed down as it wouldn't be inside the div that contains all the microposts which infact will be what I'll be prepending to.

Anyway I'd really like an example or some good advice that could help me implement this feature.

Thanks for your time
Kind regards.

Comment: So your problem is the location within the DOM in which your microposts are being inserted into?

Comment: Why don't you prepend to `.postHolder` then?

Comment: Because .postHolder is a class that holds each micropost. This would just add all the looped through microposts to .postHolder class on the page.

Comment: d_inevitable: What I'm trying to do is detect the newly posted comment by it's class then prepend it.

Comment: would filter `.postHolder` showing only the last x posts help you? or giving each post an unique id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the assumptions that you

1. want posts ordered in descending chronological order
2. would like to minimize the amount of data you have to return for an update

I would recommend that you upon successful submission of a post, you initiate an AJAX call to the server to get all posts more recent than the last displayed post.  Assuming your postholder HTML can be summarized like this

```
<div id='microposts'>
    <form id='new_post'></form>
    <div class='postholder' id='some-id-number'></div>
    <div class='postholder' id='some-older-id-number'></div>
    ...
</div>
```

I'd get the new posts as returned html from a service call

```
function getNewPosts(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Your-New-Posts-Url',
        data: {lastId: $('.postholder:first').attr('id')},
        success: function(newPosts){
            if(newPosts && newPosts.length > 0){
                $('.postholder:first').before(newPosts);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You could also use setTimeout as a heartbeat to call getNewposts every so often.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I originally thought using the id would be good but just didn't know how. I'll read up and see if this helps me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question "Can JQuery detect new classes as they appear?": No.

There are events that fire when new elements are added to a page (`DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`), but thats absolutely inefficient (and deprecated).

Better fire a custom event with jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method in the code that adds the new elements. With that you can inform independent modules that there are new elements.

But when you're looking for event handler registration on new elements, you might should have a look at jQuery's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

Comment: .live is deprecated In the latest versions  of jQuery. "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: yes, with live() I mean on() + descendant selector. But live() is about the concept, and you don't need jQuery to apply that.